# Nativescript WebView, prevent reload when navigating back on Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, nativescript

So i have setup a page, and am wanting to use an app to interact with the web page.

I am able to get data from the page by listening for certain urls, and preventing the page from webview them.

When I get this data, i navigate to a new page with a processed list.

Then when i click the back button to go back to the browser page, the browser reloads, even though its URL is already set.

Pretty simple setup:

xml:

```
<Page loaded="loaded" class="page">
    <Page.actionBar>
        <ActionBar title="Cost" icon="" class="action-bar">
        </ActionBar>
    </Page.actionBar>
    <WebView id="mywebview" />
</Page>
```

JS:

```
var checkPageLoad = function(event) {
  console.log(event.url);
  if (event.url.indexOf("mydomain") < 0) {
    if (app.ios) {
        event.object.ios.stopLoading();
    } else if (app.android) {
        event.object.android.stopLoading();
    }
  }
  if (event.url.indexOf('custom://mydomain.com') === 0 ) {

    farm(event.url.replace("custom://mydomain.com", ""));

  }
};
exports.loaded = function(args) {
  page = args.object;
  var web = page.getViewById("mywebview");
  web.on(webView.WebView.loadStartedEvent, checkPageLoad);
  if(web.android) { // in IOS android will be undefined
    web.android.setInitialScale(1);
    web.android.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    web.android.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
  }
  if (web.src != "http://myurl.com") {
    web.src = "http://myurl.com";
  }
};
function farm(item) {

  var navigationOptions={
    moduleName:'./list/list',
    context:{info: item},
    animated: true,
    transition: {
        name: "slide",
        duration: 380,
        curve: "easeInOut"
    }
  };
  var topmost = frameModule.topmost();

  topmost.navigate(navigationOptions);
}
```

So when i press the back button from the "list" page, the webview is white while it reloads.

Any Ideas? Does it have to do with the frameModule navigation?

================================================

Update 6/29/17:

I have implemented a work around for this issue. Its not the best, but it makes it work satisfactory.

To workaround: Use the NativeScripts `page`'s `showModal()` function.
http://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/navigation#modal-pages

This creates a popup, and when back is pressed it closes the popup without reloading the webview.

To implement, i had to change around a lot of how my pages were setup.

Only 1 modal page can be open at once, so each view needs to communicate with the webview page.

Pages also have an event `onShownModally`, that hands the context a little different then the frame module does.

You have to store the callback you send to the modal page, and call it when the modal page closes.

Still would like a way using just the frame module setup though.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this ?

Comment: Nope, just the work around i updated the post with.

Comment: You might want to read this: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4615#issuecomment-320937348 :D

Comment: Very awesome! if you want, you can add relevant info from that link as an answer and i will accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [was a bug in NativeScript's tns-core-modules](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4615#issuecomment-320937348).

Until the fix will be available in a public release (probably in 3.2 ?) you can use the @next version of `tns-core-modules` like this:

```
tns plugin remove tns-core-modules
npm i tns-core-modules@next --save
```

Answer (score 1):

The back button makes the last view to transit from `onPause` state to `onResume` and then `running` state. If you have access to `onResume` event, you can override it or handle it so as this reload doesn't happen when back is pressed. For example you can have a boolean value e.g. `isLoadFinished` (which you can set to `true` when loading page is finished) and checking it when `onStart` or `onResume` events are fired to prevent call to `webview.load` if `isLoadFinished` is `true`.

I am not a `nativeScript` developer, so I suggested the concept of the solution. I found [this guide](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/application-lifecycle) on android app lifecycle events in `nativeScript`, and I guess it might help you.

Comment: Hmm, i put in all the listeners, and the only one that gets fired is `activityBackPressed`. I will dig around and see what other events i can access.